# CS0023 C# Operator cannot be applied to operand of type 'string[]'

Tags: c#

I'm facing a problem

> CS0023  C# Operator cannot be applied to operand of type 'string[]'

I am using this code:

```
var list = File.ReadAllLines("E:/nadra data.txt");
int arslan = 0;

while (list.Length < 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine(arslan);
    list++;
}
Console.ReadLine();
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: what is the type of list

Comment: `list` is a `string[]` you cannot do `++` on it this way

Comment: `list` is an array of strings, what is the intention behind the invalid `list++` ?  If you want to loop consider `foreach`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/using-foreach-with-arrays

Comment: `ReadAllLines` returns an array of strings. Calling `list++` is effectively "increment the array of strings" which is why you're getting the error.. what are you trying to do?

Comment: what are you trying to do with `list++`

Comment: @EhsanSajjad than what i use? to stop my data because the data is running infinit

Comment: @Saif i am trying to stop

Comment: so you want to show just first 5 lines ?

Comment: Maybe you should start with a good c# tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_arrays.htm

Comment: @TalhaJamshaid i have tried to explain, please see the posted answers.

Comment: do you mean just print 5 lines from list?

Answer (score 2):

You're using `list++` to increment a `string[]` and that won't compile.

There's a couple more issues in your code also:

1. `list.Length` isn't going to change based on your existing code which means ...
2. your `while` loop would be endless plus ...
3. you are only outputting `arslan` which is never re-assigned so it will always be `0`

It sounds like you're treating that list as a stack or a queue.  I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines("E:/nadra data.txt");
int arslan = 0;

while (arslan < allLines.Length) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{arslan}: {allLines[arslan]}");
    arslan++;
}

Console.Write("Press any key to exit");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Try it out in [this repl here](https://repl.it/@clarkitect/StudiousRemarkableHardware)

Comment: easily converted to `while` loop.  Just be careful with those when you're new to programming; as you've discovered it's easy to let them run forever :)

Comment: There's a simple while loop in my answer and, I think, at least one other answer below.

Comment: This code is good but in my nadra file i want to print 3rd one line. in my file there are four lines

Comment: That sounds like a new question: "How can I access the third member of my array?"

Answer (score 0):

There is no '++' operator for an array. You may want to use a `foreach` loop or a `for` loop, which will hold a counter.

```
foreach(string line in list)
{
    // do something with the line
}
```

or

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.Length; ++i)
{
    string line = list[i];
    // do something with the line
}
```

Your current implementation contains also a oossible infinit loop. If list.Length *is* >=5 your loop is never executet, but if its less than five, your loop will run forever.

Comment: i want to run this using while loop

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion comments it looks like there are a lot of lines in the file and OP wants to just output 5 for now. So you can use `Take()` method for it and loop through the collection like:

```
var allLines = File.ReadLines("E:/nadra data.txt").Take(5);

foreach(var line in allLines)
   Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Here we are using `ReadLine` as it will make sure to not load all file in memory as it looks like the file is huge.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly

using `while` loop

```
   string[] List1 = new string[]{"string1", "string2", "string3" , "string4", "string5", "string6", "string7"};

    int arslan = 0;

    while( arslan < 5)
    {
        arslan++;
        Console.WriteLine(List1[arslan]);

    }
```

output :

```
string2
string3
string4
string5
string6
```